# How do I fix the average shading of many .hgt tiles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dem, hgt

I downloaded many .hgt files to map California. When I open them in QGIS, the borders line up perfectly, but the average height shading is different for each .hgt file. Is there a way to average out the height data so every file's elevation lines up and the heights are parsed the same way when exporting the full map? It seems like adding a reference min and max height would do the job.[image]

Comment: You somehow had given the answer :you could easily have set all tiles Style to have the same (global) min & max values for the grayshade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Build a virtual raster](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#gdalbuildvirtualraster) and all the tiles will be treated/symbolized as one:

[image]

[image]